# Azure : GroupsClient.BaseClient.Get(): unexpected status 403 with OData error: Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform-provider-azure, azure-service-principal

I’m trying to create the Azure AD Group using the following terraform code

```
# Required Provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0.2"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

  ....
  ....
}

data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

# Variables
variable "ad_groups" {
  description = "Azure AD groups to be added"
  type = list(object({
    display_name = string,
    description  = string   
  }))
  default = [
    {
      display_name = "Group1"
      description  = "some description"
    },
    {
      display_name = "Group2"
      description  = "some description" 
    }
  ]
}

# Create AD Groups and add the Current User
resource "azuread_group" "this"{
  count = length(var.ad_groups)
  display_name =  var.ad_groups[count.index].display_name
  description = var.ad_groups[count.index].description
  security_enabled = true
  prevent_duplicate_names = true  
  owners  = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
}
```

and I am getting the following error

```
**Error:** could not check for existing group(s): unable to list Groups with filter "displayName eq 'Group1'": GroupsClient.BaseClient.Get(): unexpected status 403 with OData error: Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

This service principal has the following roles at the Management group level

[image]

Does it need both the **Directory.ReadWrite.All** and **Group.ReadWrite.All** API Permissions? If not, what access does it need?

[image]

**Note:** If I disable the "prevent_duplicate_names = true" and apply the terraform, it throws the following error

```
GroupsClient.BaseClient.Post(): unexpected status 403 with OData error: Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to
│ complete the operation.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

By default, newly created application will have **User.Read** API permission already added to it.

I registered one new Azure AD application named **`GroupSP`** and has API permission like below:

[image]

Without adding any extra API permission, I generated one **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:<appID>
grant_type:client_credentials
client_secret:<secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to create Azure AD group with owner, I got **same error** as below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "description": "Group with designated owner",
  "displayName": "Group1",
  "groupTypes": [ ],
  "mailEnabled": false,
  "mailNickname": "srigroup",
  "securityEnabled": true,
  "owners@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>"
  ]
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, I added **`Directory.ReadWrite.All`** API permission to the service principal like below:

[image]

After granting **admin consent** to above permission, I generated access token again and ran the **same query** and got response successfully as below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "description": "Group with designated owner",
  "displayName": "Group1",
  "groupTypes": [ ],
  "mailEnabled": false,
  "mailNickname": "srigroup",
  "securityEnabled": true,
  "owners@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>"
  ]
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the Portal where Azure AD group is created, and **owner** added successfully like below:

[image]

You can also check **Audit logs** of that created group like below:

[image]

In your case, make sure to add **`Directory.ReadWrite.All`** API permission to your service principal that resolves **403 Forbidden** error.

If ***Directory.ReadWrite.All*** permission is added to the service principal, *Group.ReadWrite.All* permission is not required.

Comment: This did not work for me :/ but adding to Group Administrator yes

Answer (score 1):

I added the service Principal to Groups Administrator role in Azure AD and it worked for me.